# How does this change of log happen?

Tags: logarithms

[image]

Given this expression:

[image]

I am unable to understand how the following change of log happens. How did that expression become that result, especially yhr p2^li

Comment: I assume it is $\log_2$?  But then $-l_i=\log_2\frac 1{2^{l_i}}$ and the rest is standard.  The inequality is irrelevant.

Comment: Sure it does.  Just use the standard properties of the logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log \frac 1{p_i} - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i l_i = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log \frac 1{p_i}-p_il_i=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i (\log \frac 1{p_i}-l_i)$$
Because $-l_i$ can be represented as $\log_2 2^{-l_i}$, we substitute to get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i (\log \frac 1{p_i}+\log_2 2^{-l_i})$$
Addition of logs is just log of multiplication, so that will give you
$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i (\log \frac {2^{-l_i}}{p_i})=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i (\log \frac {1}{p_i2^{l_i}})$$